# How do I see, find or raise hidden windows on Unity desktop? 

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

When I get lots of windows on the Ubuntu 12.04 desktop, I can't find a way to see, find or select/raise the hidden windows.  This is so fundamental an issue, I'm sure some mechanism exists for this, but I don't see it.

Please explain how to see/find/raise hidden windows on the desktop.

Comment: Have you used Alt+Tab ?

Comment: Thanks for showing me super-W and Alt-Tab. But is there some option or application that presents the information in a more textual manner? I see so many small windoze that I can't tell what they are, but something with tiny icons that say "firefox" or whatever are the app-names would be much easier to deal with.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> keyboard shortcut to show a graphical overview of all windows; just click on the one you want to bring it up.

(`Super` key = `Win` key)

#### Example:

[image]

#### Keyboard-only option - `Alt+Tab`

You can also use the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> keyboard shortcut to cycle through all running applications, including minimized ones:

- Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> and keep pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle.
- Release both keys when your chosen application is highlighted.

Comment: Don't forget, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> only shows windows open on that workspace! :) For those who read this

Comment: `Win+w` doesn't do anything for me.  Did this change in the 10+ years since this was written?

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes the windows are moved out of screen.
Press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to show the window context menu, which opens on screen. Than use *move* to bring the window to the screen.

Comment: Perfect, in my case the window of Libre Calc was super small. I could see it with alt+` or super+w but not locate it. alt+space immediately located it, resizing was then trivial. Can also super+up to make fullscreen, then drag the topbar down. It will shrink again but at least you will know where it is.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is what you seek, but you can use Super+W to show an overview of all windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can also press <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> for the first icon on the launcher, and <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> for the second, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that worked for me is turning (not clicking) the mouse wheel while hovering the corresponding menu icon. The window that appears this way is not appearing with other mentioned menthods.